# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am using propTypes func and this is giving me an error only when I run the app

After I ran: ***> npm run watch***

I have no errors and everything seems to be "perfect". But when I ran the app I get the following error:

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined*

This is the piece of code that used, but still don't understand why I get this error.

```
PlanFinder.propTypes = {
    onClickBubbles: React.propTypes.func,
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a typo in the code. It should be:

```
PlanFinder.propTypes = {
    onClickBubbles: React.PropTypes.func, // PropTypes is PascalCase
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Also, this is the [official note](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) :

> React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5. Please use the prop-types library instead.

Example:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <span>Hello, {this.props.name}</span>
        );
    }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using react-router version 2.0.0

Just enter "npm install --save react-router@3.2.0"

Hope it will work.